# Apache 2.2 Virtual Host not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up a virtual host for a local site - something I've done literally hundreds of times - but something's going wrong this time.

My files are in `C:\wwwroot\TEMPLATESITE`

I have the following in my hosts file (last in a list of similar hostnames that all work)

```
127.0.0.1   templatesite.localhost.com
```

I have the following VirtualHost set up in my httpd-vhosts.conf (again, alongside a handful of other, identically set up, working sites)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.
    DocumentRoot c:\wwwroot\TEMPLATESITE
    ServerName templatesite.localhost.com
    ErrorLog logs/templatesite.-error_log
    CustomLog logs/templatesite.-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

(I've tried both with and without a trailing slash on the DocumentRoot)

Yet, no matter what I try, no matter how many times I restart Apache, or my machine, when I type in `templatesite.localhost.com` I end up at the root of `c:\wwwroot` which is my localhost root.

I'm guessing the problem is in my hosts file since the logs don't have any attempts to even access `TEMPLATESITE` so it seems like the hosts file is failing back to the generic localhost.

In that light, here's my entire hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   lmm.localhost.com
127.0.0.1   lmm2.localhost.com
127.0.0.1   prairie.localhost.com
127.0.0.1   pinegrove.localhost.com
127.0.0.1   cas-pc.localhost.com
127.0.0.1   lksu.localhost.com
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   templatesite.localhost.com
```

Thoughts?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this now. It eventually resolved. I think it was an issue of seeing different things in the admin profile.